# Ansible add multiple list variables to form a master list

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have multiple lists in my playbook, `app1`, `app2`, `app3`, ..., `appN`.
How can I merge them to a single list, called app.
I have the `N` value. What I need is this

```
app = app1 + app2 + ... + appN
```

I'm using Ansible version 2.9.18.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you are getting the values for the different `appN` values, but if you want to `flat` multiples lists into a single one, you can use the `+` operator.

Here is an example on how you might use it:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    app1: [1, 1, 1]
    app2: [2, 2, 2]
    app3: [3, 3, 3]
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        app: |
          {{
            (app | default([]))
            +
            item
          }}
      loop:
        - "{{ app1 }}"
        - "{{ app2 }}"
        - "{{ app3 }}"

    - debug:
        var: app
```

I use the `default` filter to handle the fact that the `app` variable is not defined initially. You can apply this operator in multiple ways, so you can adapt it to whatever you are using.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know I can use default like that.

Comment: Is it possible to call the set_fact inside a loop, so that I can run the same to create different variables.
app:  app1 + app2
other: other1 + other2

I don't want to create set_fact for each left side variable.

Comment: You can, but you are going to have to take care when defining the loop variables.

Answer (score 0):

And to close the gap between [@guzmonne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67639771/2123530) and your requirement, you can use a couple of a [`loop` with `range`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-sequence) and the [`vars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html) lookup.

Which gives, given that `N` is defined as an integer:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    app: "{{ app | default([]) + lookup('vars', 'app' ~ item) }}"
  loop: "{{ range(1, N+1) | list }}"
```

---

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    N: 4
    app1: 
      - a
      - b
    app2: 
      - c
      - d
    app3: 
      - e
      - f
    app4: 
      - g
      - h


  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        app: "{{ app | default([]) + lookup('vars', 'app' ~ item) }}"
      loop: "{{ range(1, N+1) | list }}"

    - debug:
        var: app
```

This yields the recap:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=1)
ok: [localhost] => (item=2)
ok: [localhost] => (item=3)
ok: [localhost] => (item=4)

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  app:
  - a
  - b
  - c
  - d
  - e
  - f
  - g
  - h

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: @Veera, here is a great example of how to do what you asked me in your comment.